# TaskConfigurer does not considering schema name for datasource

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-cloud-task

I have 2 data source. For one data source, I want to use custom schema name. For this reason, I am setting my data source url like
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.33.10/analytics?currentSchema=bahmni_mart_scdf`.
But it's creating all the tables in **public** schema, instead of **bahmni_mart_scdf** schema.

I already override TaskRepositoryInitializer bean and implements TaskConfigurer.

Here are my implementations

**DatabaseConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "martDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_mart")
    public DataSource martDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "martJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate martJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("martDb") DataSource dsMart) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsMart);
    }

    @Bean(name = "scdfDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "scdfJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate scdfJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("scdfDb") DataSource scdfDb) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(scdfDb);
    }
}
```

**DataloadTaskConfigurer.class**

```
@Component
public class DataloadTaskConfigurer implements TaskConfigurer {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    private TaskExplorer taskExplorer;

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    public DataloadTaskConfigurer(@Qualifier("scdfJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {

        this.dataSource = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        TaskExecutionDaoFactoryBean taskExecutionDaoFactoryBean = new TaskExecutionDaoFactoryBean(dataSource);
        this.taskRepository = new SimpleTaskRepository(taskExecutionDaoFactoryBean);
        this.taskExplorer = new SimpleTaskExplorer(taskExecutionDaoFactoryBean);
    }

    @Override
    public TaskRepository getTaskRepository() {
        return this.taskRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        if (this.transactionManager == null) {
            this.transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(this.dataSource);
        }
        return this.transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskExplorer getTaskExplorer() {
        return this.taskExplorer;
    }

    public DataSource getTaskDataSource() {
        return this.dataSource;
    }
}
```

**TaskConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
public class TaskConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TaskRepositoryInitializer taskRepositoryInitializerInDataMart(@Qualifier("scdfJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception {
        TaskRepositoryInitializer taskRepositoryInitializer = new TaskRepositoryInitializer();
        taskRepositoryInitializer.setDataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        taskRepositoryInitializer.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskRepositoryInitializer;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.33.10/analytics?currentSchema=bahmni_mart_scdf
spring.datasource.username=analytics
spring.datasource.password=""
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.ds_mart.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.33.10/analytics
spring.ds_mart.username=analytics
spring.ds_mart.password=""
spring.ds_mart.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the postgresql driver version. Once I update to latest version (42.2.2) everything working fine as expected

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to not override the `TaskRepositoryInitializer`, but turn it off all together via `spring.cloud.task.initialize.enable=false`.  From there, using Spring Boot, you'll want to pass in the schema for each datasource:

```
spring.datasource.schema=schema1.sql
spring.ds_mart.schema=schema2.sql
```